# Finding the most compact basis to represent a two-dimensional function

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose I have a two-dimensional function $f(x,y)$ which is symmetric under the exchange of $x$ and $y$, i.e.,  $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ and I want to represent it using a one-dimensional orthonormal basis $\{\phi_i\}$ as

$f(x,y)=\sum_{i,j} c_{ij}\phi_i(x)\phi_j(y) $.

How can I find the basis $\{\phi_i\}$ that leads to the most compact representation, i.e., it makes $c_{ij}$ decays the fastest among all possible basis sets?

========

Note: Please feel free to add more tags to this question as appropriate

Comment: What is the underlying space?

Comment: $L^2$ Square-integrable functions

Comment: $L^2$ of what space, what measure, and what are the properties of $f$?